# Why would you use lodash in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, lodash

Simple enough question I think. I see people raving about it but I haven't seen anything on the "why" use it. It doesn't seem to me (from my naïve outside perspective) ng-repeat, if not in that nested layer do ng-repeat inside another. I looks like that it doesn't add functionality that angular doesn't already have—I'm sure I'm wrong— 
  I see the term "lazy loading" being used with it and it doesn't seem like it's that much easier after seeing there docs. What are some things lodash makes significantly easier in AngularJS specifically that I would make it work adding another lib to my project? And what can you do with it that you cannot with angular out of the box?

Comment: About 95% of the lodash's functions have no built-in equivalent in AngularJS, so if you have a need for a good number of those functions, that would be a reason to use lodash.

Answer (score 5):

They're just **not the same**, and exist for distinct reasons. I think you *already know* what AngularJS *works* for, so about your questions:

**What can you do with it that you cannot with angular out of the box?**

Well, if you need to deal with several data in structures like arrays, objects or mixed/nested shapes, lodash will save you a lot of time and effort.

Maybe there's a lot of items in collections which should be presented to your client application in some particular way, you would have to write a lot of JS code in Angular controllers or services with out the aid of lodash.

If there's a lot of logic tied to your data structures and/or complex algorithms and coding workflow, go for lodash.

Lodash is a great tool, you can [get some intro here](https://egghead.io/lessons/core-javascript-introduction-to-lodash) and of course, just [check out the API reference](https://lodash.com/docs). You can use it at everywhere, either Angular or any other framework, and of course, also at Node too!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond to this I've been going through their docs for a day now but still don't quite "get it "

Comment: Well, try to follow any getting started Angular tutorial and then ... just play with lodash